# python: creating list of each element of list

Tags: python, list

I wish to create list of each element of a list.
what I want is:
    `if cities = ["detroit" , "chicago" , "portland"];`
then create 3 lists:

```
detroit = [""];
chicago = [""];
portland = [""];
```

Comment: You can doing it using `eval`, but most likely you don't want that. I think what you do want is to create a dictionary of the form `{'detroit': [], 'chicago': [], 'portland': []}`

Comment: @GeorgeKarpenkov you mean `exec`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a good idea, but that's your decision. This will do what you want.

```
cities = ["detroit" , "chicago" , "portland"]
if cities == ["detroit" , "chicago" , "portland"]:
    for city in cities:
        exec("{} = [\"\"]".format(city))
```

Comment: If you could explain the last two lines of code

Comment: Line 3 iterates over all cities, line 4 runs the statement `city = [""]` using `exec()`.

Comment: What if I need to insert a check that, create list if there doesn't exist one.
`if cities == ["detroit" , "chicago" , "portland"]:
    for city in cities:
    if len(city) == 0:
        exec("{} = [\"\"]".format(city)) `

Comment: @RahulSonwalkar Maybe you could ask a different question?

Comment: ` if cities == ["detroit" , "chicago" , "portland"]: for city in cities: if len(city) == 0: exec("{} = [\"\"]".format(city)) ` doesnt work